# div text is aligning at the baseline instead of middle

Tags: css

this is probably easier to see at the fiddle. I have social icons with their link displaying next to them. The problem is, the social icons are 40x40. The text displays at the foot of the icon. I want the text in the center of the icons. How do i pull that off? Can't seem to figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/grem28/meY8K/1/

```
<footer>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" title="Like us @ Facebook.com"><div class="footer_icon facebook"></div><div class="iconText">Facebook.com</div></a></li>
    <li><a class="inst" href="http://instagram.com" target="_blank" title="Follow on Instagram"><div class="footer_icon instagram"></div><div class="iconText">We're on Instagram</div></a></li>
    <li><a class="twt" href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank" title="Follow us @ Twitter.com"><div class="footer_icon twitter"></div><div class="iconText">Twitter.com</div></a></li>
    <li class="right"><a class="pin" href="http://www.pinterest.com" target="_blank" title="Visit Pinterest.com"><div class="footer_icon pinterest"></div><div class="iconText">Pinterest.com</div></a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
.footer_icon {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

add `vertical-align: middle` to your CSS rule for `.footer-icon`.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/g3Jk6/

Comment: wow... i was so close. I tried that on so many different elements except this one. Thanks!